# Prevent user from pasting into Excel from outside source

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to prevent my users from copying, pasting and cutting values into my worksheet.

The code below works well, except it allows users to copy something from another source (i.e. Web Browser) and paste it into the worksheet.

How might I tweak the code to prevent this?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowActivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
Application.OnKey "^c"
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Right click menu deactivated." & vbCrLf & _
"Cannot copy or ''drag & drop''.", 16, "For this workbook:"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code I wrote a few years back, maybe it will work for you?

```
Option Explicit

'+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
'| Code to selectively prevent Paste operations to specified areas |
'| of a Worksheet.                                                 |
'| Programmed by: RetiredGeek (Windows Secrets Lounge)             |
'|                aka: The Computer Mentor                         |
'|                With a little help from my friend Zeddy (WSL)    |
'| Version:  3.0                                                   |
'| Updated:  04 Jul 2015                                           |
'+-----------------------------------------------------------------+

'*** Global Variables ***
  Public rngPreventPaste As Range
  Public lSrcRows        As Long
  Public lSrcCols        As Long

Sub Auto_Open()

'+----------------------------------------------------+
'|   Remember when using OnKey the NORMAL key ACTION  |
'|   does NOT Take Place!!!                           |
'+----------------------------------------------------+

    With Application
        .OnKey "^v", "CheckCopyMode"      'Capture Ctrl+v
        .OnKey "{Enter}", "CheckCopyMode" 'Capture NumPad Enter
        .OnKey "~", "CheckCopyMode"       'Standard Enter
        .CellDragAndDrop = False          '*** Kill drag and drop! ***
    End With 'Application
    
    '*** Set parameters for initial sheet ***
'+----------------------------------------------------+
'| Next two lines only necessary if initial sheet is  |
'| a Protected sheet as it's Activate event will NOT  |
'| fire!  Change sheet name to the sheet you want to  |
'| have as the default opening sheet and set the      |
'| rngPreventPaste variable to the appropriate range. |
'| If your initial sheet is not Paste Protected use   |
'| Set rngPreventPaste = NOTHING                      |
'+----------------------------------------------------+
    
    Sheets("PasteProtectedSheet").Activate      '*** Change as necessary ***
    Set rngPreventPaste = Range("A1:C3, E5:G8") '*** Change as necessary ***
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub    'Auto_Open()

Sub CheckCopyMode()

   Dim rngPasteTarget As Range

   If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then Exit Sub '*** Nothing to copy ***!
   
   If rngPreventPaste Is Nothing Then               '*** Unprotected Sheet ***
     ActiveSheet.Paste

   Else                                         '*** Protected Range Sheet ***
   
     '*** Set Paste target Range ***
     Set rngPasteTarget = Range(ActiveCell.Address, _
                  ActiveCell.Offset(lSrcRows - 1, lSrcCols - 1).Address)

     '*** Check to make sure paste won't overlap a protected area ***
     If Not Intersect(rngPasteTarget, rngPreventPaste) Is Nothing Then
       KillPaste             'Paste overlaps protected area kill it!
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Else
       ActiveSheet.Paste     'Safe to paste do it!
     End If
   End If
   
End Sub    'CheckCopyMode()

Sub KillPaste()
'+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
'| You can change the message below to fit your needs or you can   |
'| delete it entirely. I don't recommend deleting it though as the |
'| User will have no Idea why the paste didn't work.               |
'+-----------------------------------------------------------------+

  If rngPreventPaste Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  
  MsgBox "This range: " & rngPreventPaste.Address(, , xlA1) & vbCrLf & _
         " on Sheet  : " & ActiveSheet.Name & _
         " is protected from pasting!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
         "The operation has been cancelled.", _
         vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
         "Paste operation Probited:"
         
  '*** The following statement is optional and can savely ***
  '*** be deleted I prefer it for the visual cleanup.     ***
  [A1].Select    '*** Kills the destination selection outline ***
  
End Sub      'KillPaste()
```

HTH